# Parse json_decode php

Tags: javascript, php

I've read a lot of the json_decode questions, tried a variety of different things I can't this to work.

it's the bittrex api

```
$apikey='4058';
$apisecret='50860';
$nonce=time();
$uri='https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getticker?    apikey='.$apikey.'&nonce='.$nonce.'&market=BTC-LTC';
$sign=hash_hmac('sha512',$uri,$apisecret);
$ch = curl_init($uri);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('apisign:'.$sign));
$execResult = curl_exec($ch);
$json = json_decode($execResult,true);
```

I do get an output, now I just want the "Last" value

```
{"success":true,"message":"","result":{"Bid":0.00002130,"Ask":0.00003341,"Last":0.00002121}}
```

I've tried for each

```
foreach($json->result as $market) {
 $lastPrice = $market->Last;

//this was to see if it was an echo problems, tried storing the last price in the db... I get null
 $collectionGamerActions->update(array('gamer'=>$gamer),
    array('$set'=>array('lastPrice'=>$lastPrice,'reached'=>1)));
 //print "last price is $lastPrice";
}
```

I tried

```
$lastPrice = $json->result->Last;
```

and a variety of

```
 $lastPrice = $json[0]['result']['last']
```

I gave up on php and tried javascript, 1st stringifying he response, then parsing it

```
var obj = JSON.stringify(response);
var obj =JSON.parse(obj);
console.log("last is " + obj.result.Last + " obj is " + obj);
```

nothing works... can I get direction in what I'm doing wrong please.

Tried some of the suggestions below

```
    var obj = JSON.stringify(response);
    var json = JSON.parse(response);
    console.log(json.result.Last);
```

on the php side the response is generated here

```
   $execResult = curl_exec($ch);
   $json = json_decode($execResult);

   echo json_decode($json, true);
```

results in javascript error
     SyntaxError: Unexpected number var json = JSON.parse(response);

With the php suggestions

```
 $json = json_decode($execResult);

 $json = json_decode($json, true);

 var_dump($json['result']['Last']);
```

results in NULL

Comment: Given that JSON your `$lastPrice = $json->result->Last;` works as expected. And given the `true` in `json_decode` this works also: `$lastPrice = $json['result']['Last'];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding your problem, but... assuming PHP is giving you the string you pasted above, then you can just use `JSON.parse` (no need for stringify) and grab the result from the resulting object.

```
var string = '{"success":true,"message":"","result":{"Bid":0.00002130,"Ask":0.00003341,"Last":0.00002121}}';
var json = JSON.parse(string);
console.log(json.result.Last); // 0.00002121
```

Comment: It comes up NULL regardless what I use

Comment: Hm, then I'd have to see what string your JavaScript was actually getting. I thought it was getting the exact string you posted above (and the one I started my example with).

Comment: url removed is the url, I'll delete this in a few so I don't kill my rate limit with bittrex

Comment: Yeah, that's the same string as I was using to test above- so my provided code should work, provided you're loading that string in your JavaScript. (You haven't really shown how you're passing the JSON data to your JavaScript)

Comment: Show me how you're passing that data to your JavaScript. Is it with an XML HTTP request? or something else?

Comment: got it to work... the N error was the var_dump that was on the php side

Answer (score 1):

As you use (note the second parameter in [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)):

```
$json = json_decode($execResult,true);
```

You will have an associative array, so your value will be in:

```
$json['result']['last']
```

Note that `$json->result->Last` would work if you use `json_decode()` without the second parameter (the default value, `false`).

Comment: @user2320607 You already had `true`. Just do a `var_dump($json);` and you will see directly what you need. Or post it here for us to see.

Comment: javascript unexpected token, unexpected number 
  
var obj = JSON.stringify(response);
var json = JSON.parse(response);
console.log(json.result.Last);

PHP var_dump($json['result']['Last']);
NULL

Comment: @user2320607 I am using php only, not javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Array notation (second argument to [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) is `true`):

```php
$string = '{"success":true,"message":"","result": {"Bid":0.00002130,"Ask":0.00003341,"Last":0.00002121}}';

$json = json_decode($string, true);

var_dump($json['result']['Last']);
```

Object notation (second argument to `json_decode()` is `false`):

```php
$string = '{"success":true,"message":"","result":{"Bid":0.00002130,"Ask":0.00003341,"Last":0.00002121}}';

$json = json_decode($string);

var_dump($json->result->Last);
```